# Вывод файлов php

Tags: php

Подскажите пожалуйста, как я могу вывести файлы из папки не зная названия папки?

Путь такой `/files/"неизвестное название"/89/`

Comment: узнать название папки. `ls`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы не перебирать файлы через `scandir` и проверять название файла (Хотя этот вариант тоже возможен), можно воспользоваться `glob` с флагом `GLOB_BRACE` используя регулярное выражение.

Пример (выведет файлы в папке `89`):

```php
<?php
$files1 = glob("{files/*/89/*}", GLOB_BRACE);
print_r($files1);
```

Comment: и в папке `files/87/88/89` тоже

Comment: @teran Нет. В такой папке не выведет.

Comment: Могу ли я с помощью glob получить расширения файлов?

Comment: @Владислав Самохин Да, Вы можете получить не только расширение, но и производить поиск по определённым расширениям файлов. К примеру картинки можно найти добавив `{jpg,png,gif}` Или таким же способом можно искать любые другие файлы.

Comment: @Denis640Kb поиск то понятно, а проверить расширение файлов? `pathinfo` не работает.